# How to TO provide access to the same service provider for different tenants users in WSO2 IS?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

1. I have created 2 tenants in WSO2 identity server. 
   We need to deploy a sample application to which users belonging to both the tenants should have access to using SAML 2.0.
   Please suggest how the sample application can be configured as service provider in WSO2 Identity Server to achieve this requirement.
2. Assuming that the above is done, we would also like to know how the application can identify which User belongs to which tenant once the login is successful?  is this some information that would be passed in SAML response ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the service provider in SaaS mode. With this configuration, service provider will be visible to all the tenants in the Identity Server. You can find how to configure a SaaS application from the documentation at [1]

If you want to return the tenant domain with the subject identifier in the saml response, you can enable 'Use tenant domain in local subject identifier' in 'Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration' of the service provider. More information is available in [2].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+a+Service+Provider#ConfiguringaServiceProvider-Addingaserviceprovider
[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Local+and+Outbound+Authentication+for+a+Service+Provider

Comment: Hi Maduranga, I have enabled the SaaS checkbox but the service provider cannot be accessed from a different tenant. I am getting the exception "Service Provider with the issuer 'xxx' is not registered."  Is any other configuration required to make the Service Provider discoverable across tenants?

Answer (score 0):

is olso needed to put in the url the query param for select the right tenant, I modifyed the urls in the metadata.xml generated from the WS2 IS from someting like this:

https://your-domain:9443/samlsso

to

https://your-domain:9443/samlsso?tenantDomain=tenant-name

And use this metadata.xml in the SP

Otherwise when the SP  send the saml message the IS will geneate the log "Service Provider with the issuer 'xxx' is not registered."  if your SP is not registered  in the super tenant

WSO2 IS 5.10